# Compare two Arrays and return final response based on condition

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have two arrays one is the input payload and the output payload which is coming from target api, now using these two arrays I am trying to frame final response to the end user where I need to match the id in the input payload array to the id field in output payload array and then to display the status for each of them.

input payload

```
var actualPayload = [
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY335",
    "fName": "test-335",
    "lName": "t335",
    "email": "test-335@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY346",
    "fName": "test-346",
    "lName": "346",
    "email": "test-346@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY347",
    "fName": "test-347",
    "lName": "347",
    "email": "test-347@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY120",
    "fName": "test-120",
    "lName": "120",
    "email": "test-120@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

payload from target system

```
var payload = {
    "status": "created",
    "error": "error",
    "rows": [{
        "id": "b3_12XY120",
        "status": "created"
    }]
    
}
```

Now below is my dataweave code

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
(actualPayload map (item, index) -> {
    (payload.rows map(item1, index1) ->{
        "Id": substringBefore(item.id, "_"),
        "studentId": item.id,
        "status" : if((item.id == item1.id) and (item1.status == "created" or item1.status == "updated") ) true else false,
        
       ("error" : payload.error) if((item1.id != item.id))
    })

        
})
```

The problem which I am getting with the above dataweave code is when ever the payload.rows array will not come in the case of if all the objects result in to error, then only error information will be returned from target api, but the above dataweave is not returning response in this case.

SO I want the above dataweave code to give me result when the payload.rows is not coming from the target system, then I want to frame the output response with error info coming in the error element for all of the ids in the actual payload.

When there are no rows in the target response, I want the below output to be returned from my dataweave against each of the object in the actual payload with the error mapped from what ever is in the error field in target response and for any rows returned from the target api, I want the above mentioned output coming from the dataweave.

```
[
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY335",
    "status": false,
    "error": "error"
  },
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY346",
    "status": false,
    "error": "error"
  },
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY347",
    "status": false,
    "error": "error"
  },
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY120",
    "status": false,
    "error": "error"
  }
]
```

Comment: The structure of your final output is not clear, can you also add a sample of your desired output. Also, specify how do you want the output to look like for both the cases, i.e. when there are rows in your payload from target system, and when there are not

Comment: @HarshankBansal, Edited the post and added the sample output in both cases

Comment: What response do you get from target system when there is a partial failure? Do you get them in the "rows" with status as "error"? Or is it just simply not included in the rows array and you have to just map the root level "error" for all of them?

Comment: @Harshank Bansal, When there is partial failure for some of the records or when all of them have failed, they dont come in the rows, the collection of errors will be returned in the error field as comma separated.

Comment: comma separated? but you have mapped the complete `payload.error` to each of the failed records. Like that, it will map all the errors to each failed records. Is it desired outcome? if not can you add the info about how you to know which error belong to which student record as it is coming in as comma separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the provided code is that mapping only happens when there is a rows object. Instead of this, you can do a lookup on the rows with the id. Lookup object can be created by using groupBy to group the rows in the payload by Id. This way, rows are not iterated for each item in the actual payload.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
var actualPayload = [
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY335",
    "fName": "test-335",
    "lName": "t335",
    "email": "test-335@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY346",
    "fName": "test-346",
    "lName": "346",
    "email": "test-346@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY347",
    "fName": "test-347",
    "lName": "347",
    "email": "test-347@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "b3_12XY120",
    "fName": "test-120",
    "lName": "120",
    "email": "test-120@gmail.com"
  }
]

var groupedRowsById = payload.rows default [] groupBy $.id
var statusesToMatch = ["created", "updated"]
---
(actualPayload map (item, index) -> do {
    var matchedRow = groupedRowsById [item.id]
    ---
    {
        Id: substringBefore(item.id, "_"),
        studentId: item.id,
        status: ((! isEmpty(matchedRow)) and (statusesToMatch contains (matchedRow[0].status))),
        (error: payload.error) if (isEmpty(matchedRow))
    }
})
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY335",
    "status": false,
    "error": "error"
  },
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY346",
    "status": false,
    "error": "error"
  },
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY347",
    "status": false,
    "error": "error"
  },
  {
    "Id": "b3",
    "studentId": "b3_12XY120",
    "status": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the language in the given code but I can point out the basic flaw in the code and I can provide a pseudo code to get your problem fixed.

```
1:(actualPayload map (item, index) -> {
2:(payload.rows map(item1, index1) ->{
3:    "Id": substringBefore(item.id, "_"),
4:    "studentId": item.id,
5:    "status" : if((item.id == item1.id) and (item1.status == "created" or item1.status == "updated") ) true else false, ("error" : payload.error) if((item1.id != item.id))
6:})   
7:})
```

Ok, so basic flaw in the code is that you are unnecessarily looping through the target-payload at line#2. Instead you should only find the matching object in the target-payload. Pseudo code should be like this.

```
1:(actualPayload map (item, index) -> {
2: targetObj= payload.find(x=> x.id=item.id) 
3: if (targetObj){//put your logic here if target object is found} 
4: else {// put your logic here if target object is not found}
6:})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`leftJoin`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-leftjoin) to join the two arrays, i.e. your payload and the response from the target system. It will return an array after matching each element of the payload with the respective element in the response.

```js
%dw 2.0
import leftJoin from dw::core::Arrays
import substringBefore from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
---
leftJoin(payload, vars.systemResponse.rows, (student) -> student.id, (result) -> result.id)
    map {
        Id: $.l.id substringBefore "_",
        studentId: $.l.id,
        status: !isEmpty($.r), // if r is empty that means there is no error. so status will be true
        (error: vars.systemResponse.error) if(isEmpty($.r))
    }
```